# Is there a way to speed up/remove my ndimensional numpy indexing loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, indexing

I am working with numpy indexing in a for loop and wanted to know if there is a way to do it without the loop. I have tried searching through stackoverflow but couldn't quite find an answer to my specific use case (so I apologize if this question has already been asked and answered).

Essentially I have a 3d numpy array of zeros that I am trying to fill on specific indices based on multi-dimensional indexing arrays. Here is a simplified version of my current implementation.

```
import numpy as np

# Some shape parameters (for the example)
x = 3
y = 2
h = 10
w = 12

# Create the arrays 
arr = np.zeros((x,h,w))
index_arr1 = np.array( # has shape (x,y,4)
      [[[9, 0, 7, 1],
        [1, 3, 6, 8]],

       [[8, 1, 2, 8],
        [0, 1, 0, 9]],

       [[0, 8, 7, 8],
        [0, 4, 5, 9]]])
index_arr2 = np.array([4, 8]) # has shape (y,)
value_arr = np.ones((x,y))

# Loop through the indices to fill 'arr'
for i in range(y):
    for j in range(x):
        arr[j, index_arr1[j,i], index_arr2[i]] = value_arr[j,i]
```

Is there a way to remove the loop to make the code faster and more efficient while still having the same output?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Check [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html)

Comment: @paime Thanks for your reply! I took a look at the link and tried to get it to work but couldn't quite get the dimensions correct. Would you be able to show me how it could be applied to my current case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the ranges with `arange`:

```
In [59]: I = np.arange(y); J = np.arange(x)[:,None];

In [60]: new = np.zeros((x,h,w))
In [62]: new[J[:,None], index_arr1[J,I], index_arr2[I,None]] = value_arr[J,I,None]

In [63]: np.allclose(new, arr)
Out[63]: True
```

The main challenge was that the middle index was:

```
In [64]: index_arr1[J,I].shape
Out[64]: (3, 2, 4)
```

The 1st index then has to be (3,1,1), and the last (2,1) to broadcast with this.  And `value` has to be (3,2,1).  I had to try several things before I got the indexing right.  With patience you probably could have do so as well.

`put/take_along_axis` were intended to take care of many of these details, but I haven't used them enough to apply them to your complicated cases.